# Making text dynamically larger by adding a certain class

Tags: css, font-size

Is there a way to DYNAMICALLY make text larger? Take this example:

```
* {
    font-size:1em;
}

.large {
    font-size:1.4em;
}

h1 {
    font-size:2.3em;
}
```

The problem is, when you add the large class to an element like `h1`, which has its base font size LARGER than the large class, it becomes smaller.  Is there any way to make it so that it scales it a certain percentage based on ems? I've already tried percents.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you just specify .large with percent value, and the rest with em?

Comment: I thought it would, but for some reason it didn't

Comment: Hmm, then it seems like it takes the value preceding the h1. Maybe you can use a span with .large within the h1?

Comment: Well, I would like it to work on literally any text element.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that both em and percentages are relative sizes, but they rely on the size of the *parent* element to determine the size of the child element.  You can't make something 1.4 times larger than itself any more than you can make it so that two people are taller than each other ;)

You can make any element relatively larger to its parent, so your best bet (using pure HTML and CSS) is to wrap the inner content of any element of which you want to increase the font size with a tag to which you can add the `large` class you have specified above.

Note: It looks like what we're really trying to do here is to target and style an anonymous text node inside of an element.  You can use something like `.large::first-line` to style the text larger for the first line, but I can't really say that's a solution since it will not style the entire text node.